# Can't install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop

Tags: boot, gui, gdm

Image of the problem:

[image: Image of the problem]

I received this msg while trying to install gdm3 as I had a problem it was removed and I don't know how.

It says

```
The following package have unmet dependencies:
```

I dont understand the msg or how to solve it

Comment: Pop!_OS is off-topic here.

Comment: You've 3rd party packages on your system which have created the issue. Restore your system back to a Ubuntu one and `ppa-purge` the PopOS packages (a re-install maybe easier, and please don't provide pictures of text - if it was text I could be more specific).